# Need help declaring a value for "cash".

Tags: c++

it says in the instruction "you may assume the cash to be equal or greater than the total bill". How do I declare a value for cash and make it greater than or equal to the total bill? Is my declaration of the variables for "change" "totalBill" are correct? I really need some help and like I said this is my first time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const double CHILDPRICE = 10.00;
const double ADULTPRICE = 20.50;

int main ()
{   

double adultTotal, childTotal, totalBill, change;
int childTix, adultTix, cash;



cout << "\n           Chesapeake Amusement Park" << endl << endl;

cout << "    Enter children tickets... ";
cin >> childTix;    
cout << "    Enter adult tickets...... ";
cin >> adultTix;

childTotal = CHILDPRICE * childTix;
adultTotal = ADULTPRICE * adultTix;
totalBill = childTotal + adultTotal;
change = cash - totalBill;

//The following is a sample of how you can format the output
//childTix is an integer variable
//CHILDPRICE is a double const
//childTotal is a double variable

cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2);

cout << "\n\n                 Chesapeake Amusement Park";
cout << "\n                 -------------------------";
cout << "\n\n               Tickets      Price      Total\n";

cout << "     Children   " << setw(3)  << childTix  
                           << setw(14) << CHILDPRICE 
                           << setw(11) << childTotal;

cout << "\n     Adults     " << setw(3)  << adultTix  
                             << setw(14) << ADULTPRICE 
                             << setw(11) << adultTotal;

cout << "\n ";
cout << "\n ";
cout << "\n     Total Bill                  " << setw(11) << totalBill;


//Place remaining input/output statements here
cout << "\n ";
cout << "\n ";
cout << "\n        Cash recieved...... ";
cin >> cash;

cout << "\n ";
cout << "\n ";
cout << "\n     Change                  " << setw(4) << change;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just add another prompt, and use a while loop to check that the input is greater than or equal to the desired amount

Comment: You probably want `cash` to be a `double`, just as the other "price" variables are (`adultTotal`, `childTotal`, `totalBill`).  The "you may assume" thing seems to be saying that after `cin >> cash`, you don't need to bother with a check like `if (cash < totalBill) call_police();`... just continue with your existing code (i.e. `change = cash - totalBill;` etc).  You *MUST* move the prompting for an reading of `cash` before the lines where you try to use it (`change =`).

Comment: As a general programming style guideline, if you declare the variables (e.g. "`double x;`) when you're just about to give them their initial value (e.g. `double x = 3.14;` or `if (std::cin >> x) ...`) then you won't have to worry (much) about accidentally using them before they hold a meaningful value.

Comment: AH thank you for the idea about moving the calculations before the lines where I try to use change. It solved the run time error. I changed the int = cash; into double = cash; Thank you very much sir! anyway here is my new code, if you have any suggestion please let me know.

double = cash;

change = cash - totalBill;

 cout << "\n ";
 cout << "\n ";
 cout << "\n     Change                  " << setw(11) << change;

Comment: @user3299795: looks good.  Separately, it's generally a good idea to use `if (!(std::cin >> childTix)) { std::cerr << "oops - needed a number\n"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` etc. - as is, your program could crash or misbehave if the use entered some letters instead of a number....

Comment: Also if this is to be more than a homework project I wouldn't use any floating point types. You get into a whole world of pain with rounding issues.